# Align a table column at a specific symbol

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

well met!

I need some help/advice regarding how to align a table at a specific symbol - in this case, I would like to align the table at the \to symbol

Thanks for your help! Find my MWE below!

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
    \centering
    %   \scriptsize % sets table text size
    \captionsetup{font=scriptsize} % sets the table's caption size 
    \caption{Transformation of the Cartesian coordinates under the symmetry group $D_{2}=V$ and the corresponding transformation of the Eulerian angles}
    \begin{center}
        \label{tab:tb2}
        \begin{tabular}{ccc}
            \hline
            \small{Symmetry}          & \small{Cartesian coordinate}  & \small{Euler angle}  \\
            \small{operation}         & \small{transformation}        & \small{transformation} \\
            \hline
            \multirow{3}{*}{$E$}
            & $x'\to x$                                  & $\phi'\to \phi$                         \\
            & $y'\to y$                                  & $\theta'\to \theta$                     \\
            & $z'\to z$                                  & $\chi'\to \chi$                         \\
            \multirow{3}{*}{$C_{2}(x)$}
            & $x'\to x$                                  & $\phi'\to \pi + \phi$                   \\
            & $y'\to -y$                                 & $\theta'\to \pi - \theta$               \\
            & $z'\to -z$                                 & $\chi'\to -\chi$                        \\
            \multirow{3}{*}{$C_{2}(y)$}
            & $x'\to -x$                                 & $\phi'\to \pi + \phi$                   \\
            & $y'\to y$                                  & $\theta'\to \pi - \theta$               \\
            & $z'\to -z$                                 & $\chi'\to \pi - \chi$                   \\
            \multirow{3}{*}{$C_{2}(z)$}
            & $x'\to -x$                                 & $\phi'\to \phi$                         \\
            & $y'\to -y$                                 & $\theta'\to \theta$                     \\
            & $z'\to z$                                  & $\chi'\to \pi + \chi$                   \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: unrelated but size commands do not take an argument, use `\small Symmetry` not `\small{Symmetry}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I took the liberty of adding a few points of space between each transformation.

Whereas the `tabular` builds row by row, stacks, employed here, build by the column.  Since there are three equations (x,y,z) per column, associated with each transformation, the `\alignCenterstack` is used to stack the three equations for each transformation.  The "center" part of the name indicates the result will be centered about the baseline, so that the column 1 entry will be vertically centered with respect to columns 2 and 3.  Furthermore, the stack is composed of equal baselineskips for each row, rather than equal gaps between row content.

The "align" part of the name indicates that the `&` tabbing separator can be used to mimic the `align`-style environments, allowing the rows to align at a specified point midway through the line (in this case, after the `\to`).

Note, however, that creating unique stacks for each of the `E`, `C_2(x)`, `C_2(y)`, and `C_2(z)` equations may still be misaligned with respect to each other, and for this reason, I employ `\phantom`s to make sure each of the transformation sets takes up the same horizontal width.

Finally, the `\addstackgap` adds a vertical buffer above and below its argument.  The default is `3pt`, but I reset that to `2pt` in the preamble with the `\setstackgap` invocation.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\TABstackMath
\setstackgap{S}{2pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
    \centering
    %   \scriptsize % sets table text size
    \captionsetup{font=scriptsize} % sets the table's caption size 
    \caption{Transformation of the Cartesian coordinates under the symmetry group 
            $D_{2}=V$ and the corresponding transformation of the Eulerian angles}
    \begin{center}
      \label{tab:tb2}
      \begin{tabular}{ccc}
        \hline
        \small Symmetry    & \small Cartesian coordinate  & \small Euler angle \\
        \small operation   & \small transformation        & \small transformation\\
        \hline
        $E$ &
        \addstackgap{\alignCenterstack{x'\to& x\\y'\to& y\\z'\to& z\phantom{-}}} &
        \alignCenterstack{\phi'\to& \phi\\\theta'\to& \theta\\\chi'\to& \chi\phantom{{}-\pi}} 
\\
        $C_2(x)$ &
        \addstackgap{\alignCenterstack{x'\to& x\\y'\to& -y\\z'\to& -z}} &
        \alignCenterstack{\phi'\to& \pi+\phi\\\theta'\to& \pi-\theta\\\chi'\to& -\chi} 
\\
        $C_2(y)$ &
        \addstackgap{\alignCenterstack{x'\to& -x\\y'\to& y\\z'\to& -z}} &
        \alignCenterstack{\phi'\to& \pi+\phi\\\theta'\to& \pi-\theta\\\chi'\to& \pi -\chi} 
\\
        $C_2(z)$ &
        \addstackgap{\alignCenterstack{x'\to& -x\\y'\to& -y\\z'\to& z}} &
        \alignCenterstack{\phi'\to& \phi\\\theta'\to& \theta\\\chi'\to& \pi +\chi} 
\\
\hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain what the commands you added do?

Comment: @AlexReinking I have added descriptive text.

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}


\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\newlength{\columntwo}
\setlength{\columntwo}{\widthof{Cartesian coordinate}}

\newlength{\columnthree}
\setlength{\columnthree}{\widthof{transformation}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
    \centering
    %   \scriptsize % sets table text size
    \captionsetup{font=scriptsize} % sets the table's caption size 
    \caption{Transformation of the Cartesian coordinates under the symmetry group $D_{2}=V$ and the corresponding transformation of the Eulerian angles}
        \label{tab:tb2}
        \begin{tabular}{c
                       >{\RaggedLeft}p{0.5\columntwo-2\tabcolsep}@{~$\to$~}
                       >{\RaggedRight}p{0.5\columntwo-2\tabcolsep}
                       >{\RaggedLeft}p{0.5\columnthree-2\tabcolsep}@{~$\to$~}
                       >{\RaggedRight}p{0.5\columnthree-2\tabcolsep}}
            \hline
            \small Symmetry          & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\small Cartesian coordinate}   & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\small Euler angle}  \\
            \small operation         & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\small transformation}        &  \multicolumn{2}{c}{\small transformation} \\
            \hline
            & $x'$ & $x$                                  & $\phi'$ & $\phi$                         \\
   $E$      & $y'$ & $y$                                  & $\theta'$ & $\theta$                     \\
            & $z'$ & $z$                                  & $\chi'$ & $\chi$                         \\
            \hline
            & $x'$ & $x$                                  & $\phi'$ & $\pi + \phi$                   \\
$C_{2}(x)$  & $y'$ &  $-y$                                 & $\theta'$ & $\pi - \theta$               \\
            & $z'$ & $-z$                                 & $\chi'$ & $-\chi$                        \\
        \end{tabular}
\end{table}




\end{document}
```

The exact proportions of the left and right aligned columns ight still need to be fine tuned according to the width of the contents.

[image]

Comment: Maybe you should make the right/left hand sides of the arrows considerably longer to make the alignment clearer in your MWE.

Answer (score 3):

This is just a side-remark. I personally would not add so much redundant/repeating information, which all the `<something>\to` is.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
    \centering
    %   \scriptsize % sets table text size
    \captionsetup{font=scriptsize} % sets the table's caption size 
    \caption{Transformation of the Cartesian coordinates under the symmetry group $D_{2}=V$ and the corresponding transformation of the Eulerian angles}
    \begin{center}
        \label{tab:tb2}
        \begin{tabular}{ccccccc}
            \toprule
            \small Symmetry          & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\small Cartesian
            coordinate}  &  \multicolumn{3}{c}{\small Euler angle}  \\
            \small operation         & \multicolumn{6}{c}{\small transformation}   
                \\
            & $x'$  & $y'$  & $z'$  & $\phi'$ & $\theta'$ & $\chi'$ \\
            \midrule
            $E$ & $x$ & $y$ & $z$   & $\phi$ & $\theta$ & $\chi$    \\
            $C_2(x)$ & $x$ & $-y$   & $-z$  & $\pi + \phi$ & $\pi - \theta$ & $ -\chi$  \\
            $C_2(y)$ & $-x$ & $y$   & $-z$  & $\pi + \phi$ & $\pi - \theta$ &
            $\pi-\chi$  \\
            $C_2(z)$ & $-x$ & $-y$  & $z$   & $\phi$ & $\theta$ &   $\pi+\chi$  \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]